# Updating custom table when user registers in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am looking around the code in WordPress and not sure where to look and how to complete what I am doing.

I have a custom table in Wordpress that I have created, lets call it MyCustomTable. I have some data that I want to insert in to a table when the user registers.

I want to add an ID this is auto increment and done by the table so not a problem, and want to also add in the userid and a hardcoded user group.

So when user registers the following is passed to the database.

```
INSERT INTO MyCustomTable
VALUES (this will be autoid so not needed in insert, UserID ,Hardcoded membergroup);
```

Where or how to do this?

Comment: Follow @phil advice. The Codex is where people, new and old to WordPress, go to clarify their doubts. Even if some docs are not complete, at least they serve as starting point to writing/researching your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [user_register hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) for the trigger.

If you need help with custom queries, [look here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: And [`<plugin-development>`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=frequent&pagesize=50) resourceful Q&A's.